# datepicker not work inside textbox

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

```js
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$( '#date' ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

```html
<input type="text" id="date" name="date" class='text' >
```

i search more and more but nothing works ,
datepicker not displaying or working , where is code problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It's working well, you were misplaced codes in stackoverflow snippet

```js
$(function() {
  $('#date').datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="date" name="date" class='text'>
```

For more about snippet : https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @samy : check the browser console

Comment: Can you please put the jQuery function after the form?Hope that will work for you.

Comment: thanx bootstrap make a problem of using external javascript .. thanks for help

Comment: yup it waking know